# Passing javascript array via POST to PHP does not working

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, post

I need to pass a javascript array, via POST, to a PHP file.

I've tried to semplify my original business trying to explain my troubles ...

This is my first PHP file, in which I declare a javascript array and I set each element to 1 value (not a great business I know, but it doesn't matter, it's only to explain ....)

```
<?php

  echo '<form action="testPhp-2.php"  method="POST" target="testPhp-2">';

  echo '<script type="text/javascript">';

  echo 'var arr_selections = [];';
  echo 'for(i=0; i < 10; i++)';
  echo ' {';
  echo '  arr_selections[i] = 1';
  echo ' }';

  echo 'arr_selections_json = JSON.stringify(arr_selections);';
  echo 'alert (arr_selections[2]);';

  echo 'document.write("<br/>");';
  echo ' ';

  //        echo 'document.write("<input type="hidden" />");';
  echo 'document.write("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"arr_selections_json\" value=\"arr_selections_json\" />");';
  echo ' ';

  echo '</script>';

  echo '    <input type="submit" value="Controlla">';
  echo '   </form>';


?>
```

.... and here you are the code of testPhp-2 file ...

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['arr_selections_json']))
   {
    echo "OK, array exist !! ";
    echo '</br>';
    echo '</br>';
    $arr_selections = json_decode($_POST['arr_selections_json'], true);
    echo $arr_selections[0];
   }
  else {
   echo "NO; array does not exist !! ";
   echo '</br>';
   echo '</br>';
  }

?>
```

Now, if you try to execute the code you'll see the **OK, array exist !!** message but no array value is printed about the ***echo $arr_selections[0];*** line of code in testPhp-2.php file.

Any suggestion will be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Cesare

Comment: Have you checked `$_POST['arr_selections_json']` value?

Comment: You're passing the literal string `arr_selections_json` to the input field. That's all.

Comment: You should checkout the HEREDOC syntax, would be much less painful of an experience to write Javascript in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois .. do you mean that the problem is in this line of code in testPhp-1.php file? echo 'document.write("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"arr_selections_json\" value=\"arr_selections_json\" />");'; How may I fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you're setting the value of the input to the litteral string `"arr_selections_json"` instead of to the contents of that variable.

Change

```
echo 'document.write("... value=\"arr_selections_json\" />");';
```

To

```
echo 'document.write("... value=\""+arr_selections_json+"\" />");';
```

Comment: GREAT! It's working now .. this is out of my knowledge. Thanks a lot!